# C++ STL array compiler problem on code block

Tags: stl

Every time I try running this program my compiler throws an error saying error: no matching function for call to 'begin(int*&). Is it that my compiler is not supporting this standard template.
I am using a code block. I even tried installing c++11 ISO C++ language standard [-std=c++11] but it didn't work either.

```
 array<int,5> arr={1,2,3,4,5};
    for(auto it:arr.begin();it!=arr.end();it++)
    {
        cout<<*it<<" ";
    }
```

Comment: `for (auto it : arr) { cout << it << " "; }`

Answer (score 0):

Replace "auto it:arr.begin()" to "auto it = arr.begin()" and it should work

Comment: No biggie. @BimarshKhatri if you take a look at JohnnyMopp's comment, you can achieve the same result in C++11 syntax (which is a more preferred form)